# Wait for window content change or appear in Imacros

Tags: imacros

```
1   VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
2   SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
3   SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 35
4   TAB T=1
6   TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Click<SP>here<SP>to<SP>earn
7   Wait Seconds=35
```

this is my code for some website i maked a fixed time but it actually it's a random time so how can i make imacros check this 'You can go back' text appear then continue the script without the 'WAIT' time

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the next step you want (like search for the "next" button) but add a `SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1000` (Any high number of seconds) before it and so instead of trying for 6 seconds (the default) and failing to find it iMacro will retry the action until the condition (STEP) matches or if the time runs out it will act as if the emelent was not found.

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 35
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Click<SP>here<SP>to<SP>earn
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 600   ' or any other # of sec you think is ok
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:You<SP>Can<SP>Go<SP>Back  'or other commands like search source
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6   ' remember to set back to 6 to not get stuck on other commands
```

http://wiki.imacros.net/!TIMEOUT_STEP

Comment: what code did you add to search for the next element?
my "TXT:You<SP>Can<SP>Go<SP>Back " was just an example and will not work out of the box for you. you need to replace with the relevant code. you can wait for it to load and record clicking on it with the browser record option and then past the code instead of my next to last line. or send a link to the page you are trying to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var macro,retcode;

macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:You<SP>can<SP>go<SP>back" + "\n";
retcode = iimPlay(macro);

while (retcode < 1) {
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:You<SP>can<SP>go<SP>back" + "\n";
retcode = iimPlay(macro);
}
```

[link return error in imacros](http://wiki.imacros.net/Error_and_Return_Codes)